# Missing auth or preview (View: /Users/am-macmini-ftndw/Desktop/Lass/enrollca/resources/views/layouts/partials/gtm-head.blde

Tags: laravel

I don't know what is the problem and don't know how to solve it.

**GoogleTagManager**:

```
namespace App\Helpers;

public function __construct(array $config)
{
    if (!isset($config['auth']) || !isset($config['preview'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Missing auth or preview');
    }
```

**gtm-header.blade**:

```
@php
  $gtm = app(App\Helpers\GoogleTagManager::class);

@endphp
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TWRGZ2F');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager --
```

**Error**:

> Missing auth or preview (View:
> /Users/am-macmini-ftndw/Desktop/Lass/enrollca/resources/views/layouts/partials/gtm-head.blade.php)

Comment: are you sure you have `gtm-header.blade.php` is present `resources/views/layouts/partials` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the config array that should be passed to the constructor of `App\Helpers\GoogleTagManager::class`. One way to fix this would be to bind that class using the IoC container in a service provider. Another option would be to instantiate the class in a view composer (using the config array of course). If both of these terms sound unfamiliar, I'd advise you to look them up in the laravel manual.